# Regex to identify orphan lsquo inside or outside of double-quoted string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex to find an orphan lsquo (‘), whether inside or outside of l/rdquo (“”).
Orphan outside of a double-quote means no rsquo (’) before another lsquo, or the end-of-string.
Orphan inside of a double-quote adds an rdquo to the above two terminations.
Contractions and elided words (rsquo followed by letters) should be ignored, e.g. “‘this’s an orphan lsquo” and “‘so ‘s this.”

The goal is to match the ‘orphan in the lines below, and not match the lines without one. In the case of `’another lsquo`, although that is technically another orphan, it's not important, i.e. identifying the first orphan is sufficient. If both are caught, great, but only the first one is required.

I came up with `(“[^“]+?”[^‘]*)*‘(.(?!’[^A-Za-z]))+(‘|$)`, but it doesn't stop at the line boundary so only works if operating on a single line at a time, and it doesn't allow a terminating rdquo if it's inside a double-quote. I tried to solve the line-boundary problem by adding `|$` on the `[^` character classes, but that didn't work; I'm sure it's something obvious, but there's still the terminating rdquo if in double quote issue. (All of the parens can be non-capturing, I just left it out for legibility.)

```
“double-quote,” and some text
Some text and “double-quote” and an ‘orphan
“double-quote,” some text and ‘matched l/rsquo’
Some text and “double-quote” and an ‘orphan and an ’elided word
“double-quote,” ‘matched l/rsquo’ and an ‘orphan and ’elided word
Some text, “double-quote,” more text, an ‘orphan and a contract’n
“double-quote,” some text, and another “double quote.”
“double-quote,” some text, an ‘orphan and “another double-quote”
“double-quote,” a ‘matched l/rsquo with an “embedded double-quote” in it.’
“double-quote,” a ‘matched l/rsquo with an “embedded double-quote” in it’ and an ‘orphan.
“double-quote,” some text, an ‘orphan, a contract’n, and “another double-quote”
“double-quote,” some text, another “double-quote,” an ‘orphan and a contract’n
“double-quote” and “another double-quote” and an ‘orphan and ‘another lsquo
“double-quote” and some text and an ‘orphan and ‘a matched l/rsquo’
Some text and “double-quote” and an ‘orphan and ‘a matched l/rsquo with a contract’n’
some text and an ‘orphan
some text and an ‘orphan and an ’elided word
some text and an ‘orphan and a contract’n
some text ‘orphan, another ‘lsquo, and more text
some text ‘orphan, a contract’n, another ‘lsquo and ’elided word and more text
some text, an ‘orphan and a “double-quote with ‘matching l/rsquo’” and more text

Some text, “double quote, with an ‘orphan inside.”
Some text, “double quote, with a ‘matched l/rsquo inside.’”
Some text, “double quote, with an ‘orphan and contract’n inside.”
Some text, “double quote, with an ‘orphan and ’elided word inside.”
Some text, “double quote, with an ‘orphan and ‘matched l/rsquo inside.’”
“‘Orphan immediately following double-quote.”
“‘Matching l/rsquo immediately inside double-quote.’”
“‘Orphan immediately following double-quote with ‘matched l/rsquo’ inside.”
“Double quote,” another “double quote with an ‘orphan and ‘matched l/rsquo’”
“double quote,” another “double quote with an ‘orphan and contract’n and ‘matched l/rsquo’ and more text”
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know which of the lines in your sample text are supposed to be matched

Comment: Please add a tag to show what language you are using because different regex engines have different capabilities.

Comment: First sentence of second paragraph: "The goal is to match the ‘orphan in the lines below, and not match the lines without one."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the orphaned left single quotes:

```
‘(?!(?:“[^”\n]*”|[^‘”\n])*’(?![a-z]))
```

This matches:

- `‘` : a left single quote
- `(?!` : a negative lookahead for:
- `(?:“[^”\n]*”|[^‘”\n])*` : zero or more of **either**

  - `“[^”\n]*”` : a double quoted string (not including a newline); or
  - `[^‘”\n]` : a character which is not a left single quote, right double quote or newline
- `’(?![a-z])` : a right single quote which is not followed by a letter

We are using the lookahead to match the remainder of any valid single quoted string; since it is a negative lookahead it will fail in those cases, thus matching only orphaned left single quotes.

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HA2Tl2/1)